# Обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более

Tags: c++, классы

Имею код. Класс, реализация и главная функция. Когда всё находится в одном файле cpp - всё работает. Попытался отделить реализацию класса от интерфейса - получил 2 ошибки. 
В чем может быть проблема?

machine.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MACHINE_H
#define MACHINE_H
class Machine {
public:
    char name[50]; // название станка
    float kol; // количество отработанных часов
    float kolH; // количество изготовленных деталей за час

    void TEST(void);
    void TASK2(const Machine* arr, size_t n);
    void INIT(void);
    void SHOW(void);

    Machine();
    Machine(const char* na, float ko, float koH);
    Machine(const Machine& obj);
    ~Machine();
    };

#endif
```

machine.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "machine.h"
using namespace std;
float kool = 0;

Machine::Machine() {
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе по умолчанию.\n";
    strcpy(name, "СтанокВторой");
    kol = 3;
    kolH = 8;
}

Machine::Machine(const char* na, float ko, float koH) {
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе с параметрами.\n";
    strcpy(name, na);
    kol = ko;
    kolH = koH;
}

Machine::Machine(const Machine& obj) {
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Этот обьект был создан в конструкторе копирования.\n";
    strcpy(name, obj.name);
    kol = obj.kol;
    kolH = obj.kolH;
}

void Machine::TEST(void) {
    kool += kol;
}

Machine::~Machine() {
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Удаление объекта деструктором.\n";
}

void Machine::SHOW(void) {
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Информация о станке:\n";
    cout << "\nНазвание станка > " << name;
    cout << "\nКоличество отработанных часов > " << kol;
    cout << "\nКоличество изготовленных деталей за час > " << kolH;
}

void Machine::INIT(void) {
    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Введите данные о станке:\n";
    cout << "\nНазвание > "; cin >> name;
    cout << "\nКоличество отработанных часов > "; cin >> kol;
    cout << "\nКоличество изготовленных деталей за час > "; cin >> kolH;
}

void Machine::TASK2(const Machine* arr, size_t n) {
    size_t i_min = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        if (arr[i_min].kol > arr[i].kol)
            i_min = i;

    std::cout << arr[i_min].name << std::endl;
}
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "machine.h"
using namespace std;
float kool = 0;

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");

    Machine M1("Станок_Большой", 32, 68);
    M1.SHOW();
    Machine M2;

    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("1.txt");
    fout << M1.name << " " << M1.kol << " " << M1.kolH;
    fout.close();

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("1.txt");
    fin >> M2.name >> M2.kol >> M2.kolH;
    fin.close();

    cout << "\nИнформация про станок 2:\n";
    M2.SHOW();

    fin.open("1.txt");
    fin.seekg(0);
    cout << "\nПотоковый вывод содержания 1.txt\n";
    char ch;
    while (fin.get(ch))
        cout << ch;
    cout << "\n\nВывод закончен\n\n";
    fin.close();

    M1.TEST();
    M2.TEST();
    cout << "Количество отработаных часов (общее): " << kool;

    cout << endl << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Заполнение массива экземпляров ma";

    Machine ma[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "\nВвод информации про " << i + 1 << " объект";
        ma[i].INIT();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "\nВывод информации про " << i + 1 << " объект";
        ma[i].SHOW();
    }

    cout << "\n\nНазвание станка, который имеет наименьшее количество отработанных часов -->> ";
    ma -> TASK2(ma, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Ошибки:

```
1)
Ошибка  LNK2005 "float kool" (?kool@@3MA) уже определен в machine.obj
2)
Oшибка  LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более  ПР 6
```

Comment: Зачем вы в обоих .cpp определили переменную `float kool;`? Чего вы хотели добиться?

Comment: @Croessmah, определил 2 раза из-за того, что если этого не сделать хотя-бы в одном файле, то я получу ошибку: 
kool: необъявленный идентификатор

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float kool = 0;` во всей программе может быть только один. Его нужно оставить только в одном .cpp файле (по смыслу - в `machine.cpp`).

Чтобы его можно было использовать из других файлов, нужно использовать `extern float kool;`. Чтобы не писать это в каждом файле, лучше поместить в хедер (`machine.h`).

---

Или, если у вас достаточно новый компилятор, вместо всего этого можно в хедере (`machine.h`) написать `inline float kool = 0;` (и убрать `float kool = 0;` из всех файлов).

Answer (score 0):

просто сделай его не float, а static float и всё заработает.

```
#pragma once
static float dt;
```